# getResources.getString(R.string.hello_world) not working when i changed my language to french

Tags: android, string

[image]I have 3 string files for 3 different languages(`English en`, `French fr`, `Spanish sp`). When i change the language from `en` to `sp` everything works fine. If I change it to `fr` it says **Resource id not found**. The resource is available in 3 string files. How can i achieve to get `fr` language?

> Process: com.bhaskar.project, PID: 19377
>    [image: Error]  android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f0f0059

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding the project?

Comment: Yes i have tried for multiple times and reinstalled the app

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: itemPoolCalculator = new ResideMenuItem(this,getResources().getString(R.string.btn_pool_calc),R.drawable.sidearrow);
        itemDosage = new ResideMenuItem(this,getResources().getString(R.string.btn_dosage),R.drawable.sidearrow);
        itemVideos = new ResideMenuItem(this,getResources().getString(R.string.btn_videos), R.drawable.sidearrow);
        itemBlogs = new ResideMenuItem(this,getResources().getString(R.string.btn_articles),R.drawable.sidearrow);
        itemResources = new ResideMenuItem(this,getResources().getString(R.string.btn_training),R.drawable.sidearrow);

Comment: I'm getting error at R.string.btn_pool_calc, R.string.btn_dosage, R.string.btn_videos saying that Resource not found. But all those fields are available in my strings.xml

Answer (score 1):

***Try below code.***
*for language change i made one function you have to pass language code and context.*

language="en"
set language as per your requirement(English en, French fr, Spanish sp) 
context pass your activity/fragment  context

```
public static boolean setLangRecreate(String language, Context context) {
    try {
        Configuration config = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        config.locale = locale;
        context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        // recreate();
        ((Activity) context).finish();
        ((Activity) context).overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
        ((Activity) context).startActivity(((Activity) context).getIntent());
        ((Activity) context).overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```